# Regular expression get info from string

Tags: php, regex

How do I fill an array like this:

```
array('0' => 'blabla','1' => 'blabla2')
```

from a string like this:

```
'#blabla foobar #blabla2'
```

using `preg_match()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) for that:

```
preg_match_all('/#(\S+)/', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$matches = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "#wefwe dcdfg qwe #wef";
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "#wefwe"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "#wef"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "wefwe"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "wef"
  }
}
```

That is one way to do it :-)